# Термін придатності необмежений чи без обмежень?

Tags: вживання-слів, синоніми

СУМ-11

> ***[Необмежений](http://sum.in.ua/s/neobmezhenyj)*** 1. Який не має видимих меж; безмежний.  //  Який не має обмежень, не поставлений ні в які рамки.
>
> 2. Дуже великий щодо кількості, ступеня вияву.

В [словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) немає слова без обмежень, лише [безмежний](http://sum.in.ua/s/bezmezhnyj).

Коли говоримо про термін придатності товару, яке слово правильно вживати необмежений чи без обмежень? Чи можна використовувати обидва слова, як взаємозамінні?

Answer (score 2):

Термін придатності саме *необмежений*, бо у нього немає *межі*. Порівняйте з [обмежена множина](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Якщо ж ми кажемо, що термін придатності *без обмежень*, тобто на нього не накладено обмежень, то це не означає, що він *необмежений*, бо той хто визначав цей термін придатності міг не скористатись відсутністю обмежень, наприклад тому, що покупці часто думають, що раз менший термін придатності, то продукт натуральніший.

Comment: Будь ласка, перефразуйте Вашу відповідь бо важко зрозуміти пояснення в другому абзаці. Дякую.

Comment: @BohdanKuts що саме вам не зрозуміло?

Comment: У Вас весь абзац одним реченням. І, на жаль, мені не вдалось зрозуміти що саме Ви мали на увазі, коли написали _це не означає, що він необмежений_ і навели приклад. Що тоді воно означає?
І яке відношення має відсутність змоги скористатися відсутністю обмежень до думок покупців та оцінки натуральності продукту?

Comment: @BohdanKuts *без обмежень* - це дія зовні - його не обмежили. *необмежений* - це його характеристика - у нього немає меж.

Comment: Дякую, стало трохи зрозуміліше. Проте частина про "покупців" і їхнє ставлення до терміну придатності все ще залишається не зовсім зрозумілою.

Answer (score 0):

Гадаю, що потрібно вживати слово "необмежений".

Глянемо на [Закон України «Про якість та безпеку харчових продуктів і продовольчої сировини»](http://search.ligazakon.ua/l_doc2.nsf/link1/Z970771.html) від 23.12.1997, де пише:

> 16. Експлуатаційний дозвіл має **необмежений** строк дії.

Словосполучення "без обмежень" в законі не вживається.